# Swip to delete though ItemTouchHelper RecyclerView?

Tags: android, swipe-gesture, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement **swip-to-delete** `RecyclerView` with ItemTouchHelper onSwiped method. problem is, it gives us adapter position. but how to retrieve items's actual sql id from cursor loader? I am using `CursorLoader` and `ContentProvider`. kindly guide

```
    public class ActivityTaskList extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


......
            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            int pos1 = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            deleteData(pos1);
            Log.d(TAG,"onSwiped");
                         };

        private void deleteData(long adapterPosition) {
         Uri uri = Uri.parse(TaskProviderP.CONTENT_URI + "/"+ (int)adapterPosition);
            getContentResolver().delete(uri, null,null);

            Log.d(TAG,"deleteData");
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader");
            String[] projection = { TaskTableP.COLUMN_ID, TaskTableP.COLUMN_NAME,TaskTableP.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION };
            CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,
            TaskProviderP.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
            return cursorLoader;
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLoadFinished");
            taskAdapterP.setCursor(cursor);
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onLoaderReset");
            taskAdapterP.setCursor(null);
        }
    }
```

Attached my Adapter class for reference. I think Nilesh's solution needs some kind of list or array. i am new bee and confuse in this.

```
public class TaskAdapterP extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapterP.TViewHolder> {


    private Context context;

    public TaskAdapterP(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        setHasStableIds(true);

    }
    private Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return super.getItemId(position);
    }
    public void setCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        this.cursor = cursor;
        Log.d(TAG, "setCursor");
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public TViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.one_task_row, parent, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");
        return new TViewHolder(view);
    }





    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder");
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            holder.vhTask_Title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TaskTableP.COLUMN_NAME)).replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>", ""));
            holder.vhTask_Description.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(TaskTableP.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount");
        return cursor == null ? 0 : cursor.getCount();
    }
    class TViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView vhTask_Title, vhTask_Description;
        public TViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.d(TAG, "TViewHolder Constructor");
            vhTask_Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_task_name);
            vhTask_Description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_task_description);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Solution is 
write `getID` method in adpter that will `return` id of supplied **positioin**

```
public int getID(int positioin) {
        return visitingCards.get(positioin).getNo();
    }
```

And call `getID` using adapter object like this

```
 mAdapter.getID(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition())
```

---

**Update**
for your adapter you can do like

```
public int getID(int positioin) {
        return cursor.moveToPosition(position).cursor.getXXX(YOUR_COLUM_NAME);// so that will return id
    }
```

Comment: thanks Nilesh, i have added my adapter class for reference. is your solution needs list or array ? As new bee i am very confuse in list array and cursor. can we use them wise versa. ??